# Count of objects differs from count of keys if box is unchecked?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a set of check boxes on my view controller, and they work great. Long story short: A user checks a box, and then taps the save button. Saving after checking a box posts the value 'yes' to a field in my database. However if no box is checked, and my user taps 'save', I'm thrown this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of
>   keys (1)'

How can I stop the app from crashing if no box is checked, as checking a box is not mandatory? Code below (let me know if you need more - removed convoluted 'save' part of button action).

**viewcontroller.m**

```
- (IBAction)myCheck:(id)sender {

    if (!checked17) {

        [myCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked17 = YES;

        self.box = @"Yes";

    }

    else if (checked17) {

        [myCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked17 = NO;

            self.box = @"No";
    }


}

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

    NSDictionary *petOption = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.box, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *checkedFinish = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:petOption] forKey:@"und"];


    [nodeData setObject:checkedFinish forKey:@"field_haveapet"];

}
```

Comment: Do you have exception breakpoints enabled? This shows how to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode . Crash your app after enabling this breakpoint and it should show you the exact line on which it crashes.

Comment: @Losiowaty This is the crash line:   NSDictionary *petOption = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.checkBox, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];

Answer (score 1):

The `dictionaryWithObjects` counts array size until first `nil` appears.

So when `self.box` is `nil` the first argument is treated as empty array here:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.box, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]
```

you need to handle this situation differently, explicitly creating empty `NSDictionary` when `self.box` is `nil`, for example.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to initialize `self.box` in `viewDidLoad` with correct initial value.

Comment: I ended up "fixing" it by dropping the following line in before my crash line:    if (self.box == (id)[NSNull null] || self.spayed.length == 0 ) self.box = @"N/A";